# MacBook Display Randomly Goes Black

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

There’s something wrong with my 2019 MBP display. It flickers a little every now and then and then the screen goes black and unresponsive. If I then shut the lid and open it up again, the display comes back on again. Sometimes, the Apple logo will load for a second before displaying whatever was open before it went black. I have reset the SMC and NVRAM and it didn’t seem to help. No issues with external display when I connected one to check. Any ideas what could help?

Comment: How often do you restart your computer?

Comment: About once a day or every other day ordinarily but a few times a day since this issue started because I was trying to see if rebooting would fix it